# JSON parsing trouble with an array of strings

Tags: json, parsing

I'm having trouble getting this to parse, [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is indicating that "frames" is undefined, but it looks perfectly legal to me.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
{
    "textureFile":"test.png",
    "cycles":
        [
            [0, 1],
            [1, 0],
            [1],
            [2]
        ],
    "frames":
        [
            "   0     40    25    25    10    10",
            "   +      -     =    50     5     ="
        ]
}
```

Comment: JSONLint says "valid JSON" when I try.

Comment: @ayhan - w-what?  ... oh, I think I know what the problem is now

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the exact error jsonlint gives you? The version you pasted on this page parses fine, but your version might contain weird control characters or something equally funny.

Answer (score 0):

the document as it appeared on this question parses perfectly into jsonlint, so I compared it with the version I had saved, with whitespace visible, and found the problem:

[image]

The one tab character before the zero in the first string breaks json's rules on what constitutes a valid string character.  Tabs are accepted only as escaped '\t', but natural tabs like these will break things.